# changing permalink 'next' page not found

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my site I have a `custom post type` `advice` and `custom taxonomy` `advice-cat` and all post in `advice` display in `advice page` I use `next` and `prev` `link` to limit post, display in every page, I limit it to display 5 post only in every page. It's working until I change the permalink into `Custom Structure` something like this `/%category%/%post_id%`, then when I click the `next link` to navigate the next page, it display `page not found` and then I try to change the permalink like this `/post/%post_id%`, the next page now back to work. and I try another structure like this /%author%/%post_id%`, the next page again not working.

anyone have and idea why if i use a permalink to be `dynamic` when I click the `next link` to navigate the `next page`, and error occur `page not found`.

Answer (score 0):

First set permalink to `post type`. You can replace `page.php` file. It will help you to set `permalinks` again.